# Animated element not visible outside of parent container in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations, css-position

I have a animated div that flies to the top right corner of the viewport.

However, because of the `overflow` properties it not visible outside of parent container in Firefox. It is perfectly visible in Chrome.

Element behind the scrollbar in Firefox:

[image: Element behind the scrollbar in Firefox]

Element correctly above the parent in Chrome:

[image: Element correctly above the parent in Chrome]

How can I make it work in Firefox as well? If `overflow-y: auto` is removed from `.container` the issue doesn't appear anymore, but that's not a viable solution as I need the scrollable content.

Here is an example. You can check that it produces the desired behaviour in Chrome, but not in Firefox:

```css
.app {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 260px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 5px;
  position: sticky;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}



@keyframes fly-to-top {
  10% {
    top: 150px;
    right: 80%;
    width: 50px;
  }

  30% {
    top: 120px;
    right: 70%;
    width: 45px;
  }

  60% {
    top: 75px;
    right: 40%;
    width: 40px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 10px;
    right: 160px;
    width: 35px;
  }
}


.animated {
  position: fixed;
  right: unset;
  top: 165px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  animation: fly-to-top linear 2s forwards;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="animated">
        Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after comment:

You can take the animated element out of its parent (i.e. the element which has `overflow: hidden`), on a higher level in the HTML code - as a sibling to the container. I did that in the snippet below, and also added a `z-index` that places the animated element above the container:

```css
.app {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 260px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 5px;
  position: sticky;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes fly-to-top {
  10% {
    top: 150px;
    right: 80%;
    width: 50px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 120px;
    right: 70%;
    width: 45px;
  }
  60% {
    top: 75px;
    right: 40%;
    width: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10px;
    right: 160px;
    width: 35px;
  }
}

.animated {
  position: fixed;
  right: unset;
  top: 165px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  animation: fly-to-top linear 2s forwards;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 501;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animated">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I wasn't clear enough in my post. I *want* the element to fly outside of the parent container to the top right of the viewport. However, in Firefox the element is not visible outside of the parent container. I will try to improve my post.

Comment: Please note that I edited my answer including the snippet according to the comment I had written as a response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a valid solution, although it's sadly not the most practical. I was hoping to find a way to make the existing setup work in Firefox, given it works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: I eventually end up going for this -  although I'm using react so with the use of `React.Portal` which allows me to place the element in my desired location in the code. However, I awarded the bounty to the other answer, because it was closer to what I was asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this splution:

1. `.wrapper` position set to **fixed**
2. `.content` is shifted down with `transform: translateY()`
3. In the `.wrapper` class, i was add `pointer-events: none;`, because
   if cursor is on the `.wrapper` block without this property, mouse
   wheel cann't scroll the content, scroll work only when drag the
   scroll bar.

```css
.app {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 260px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  /* top: 5px; */

  position: fixed; /* changed */
  /* calculate '.container' width - scroll-track-width(12px-17px) - '.wrapper' padding(left, right) - margin(left, right) */
  width: calc(260px - 12px - 20px - 10px);
  z-index: 5;
  pointer-events: none; /* mouse wheel work with this property */
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
  /* calculate '.wrapper' properties to shift '.content' down  */
  /* height + padding(top, bottom) + margin-bottom */
  transform: translateY(calc(250px + 20px + 5px));
}

@keyframes fly-to-top {
  10% {
    top: 150px;
    right: 80%;
    width: 50px;
  }

  30% {
    top: 120px;
    right: 70%;
    width: 45px;
  }

  60% {
    top: 75px;
    right: 40%;
    width: 40px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 10px;
    right: 160px;
    width: 35px;
  }
}

.animated {
  position: fixed;
  right: unset;
  top: 165px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  animation: fly-to-top linear 2s forwards;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="animated">
        Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you perhaps know what is the cause of different behaviours between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Chrome uses a **Blink** engine and Firefox uses **Gesko / Quantum** engine and in this case, we have some times problem with difference render view on the canvas. Otherwise, it might be the bug of Firefox or Chrome and you can ask about this behaivor on the official forum.